# How to change '#' column name in Yii2 GridView?

Tags: yii2

I am new to Yii2 framework and I have strange question. Is it possible to rename `GridView` column `#`? I've searched for it in `index`, `layout` and etc, but couldn't find where it can be done.

I uploaded the image what I need to rename:

```
http://imageshack.com/a/img923/3491/ym6Tg0.png
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this column is `SerialColumn`. In this case just configure it with different header like:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
    'header' => 'Your new name here',
]
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Maybe could you also tell me is it possible to sort and filter that column? I'm thinking that this column is not one of the database tables

Comment: This column has nothing to do with database, it's just displaying number of the row, starting from 1 - sorting and filtering it makes no sense.

Comment: I think that it has some sense. F.e If i would enter a new user, in `GridView` it would be displayed as the last row, but if I would want to display last entered users at the top, it could be useful

Comment: It's better to use database row identifier for that, usually it's column named `id`.

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely right, I forgot about `id` in the database... Thank you, Bizley.